# Showing RavenDB request in test result output

Tags: ravendb

I would like all calls made to RavenDb to be shown in the Resharper testrunner when i run my tests, is there some kind of logging or tracing that can be turned on in the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelle,
RavenDB uses NLog under the covers to log its actions. You can configure NLog to output everything from Raven.Client.* to the console / debug, you can do it with the following configuration:

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.netfx35.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="Console" Name="Console" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="Raven.Client.*" writeTo="Console"/>
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just something that's off the top of my head. I use Resharper and NUnit or XUnit. To get any info in the Resharper unit test output window, I just use `Debug.WriteLine("blah");` Works great.

Now RavenDb does have some places you can add your own custom logic, such as `Debug.WL(..)` by creating your own `IDocumentQueryListener`'s ..

So maybe implement one of them?

```
public class DebugWriteLineDocumentListener : IDocumentQueryListener
{
    #region Implementation of IDocumentQueryListener

    public void BeforeQueryExecuted(IDocumentQueryCustomization queryCustomization)
    {
        // Do whatever you want, here.
        // UnTested .. but I *think* the ToString will list the Linq query.
        Debug.WriteLine(queryCustomization.ToString());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then just register this listener with your `DocumentStore` ...

```
documentStore.RegisterListener(new DebugWriteLineDocumentListener());
```

See if that helps ..

I've not tried it .. just the first thing that came into my head :)

GL! Keep us posted!